# Reset UAC on a folder after permitting access

Tags: windows, uac

When I access a folder in Program Files I get a UAC prompt confirming with me that I want to permit access to it. I say "yes" and get permanent access.

My question is: how do I reset this folder so that it prompts me again.

The reason I ask is that I am testing a .NET program I wrote that deals with directory access permissions and I need to test it with the UAC protection on. But now that I have permitted access manually, I can't figure out how to turn the UAC protection back on to retest my program.

Comment: Win Vista or 7?

Comment: I would like to know for both.

Answer (score 2):

It's not UAC, it is just a Windows dialogue that makes it easy to change the NTFS permissions on the folder. The UAC prompt is triggered because you are changing permissions, but the permission change itself is not a function of UAC.

[This](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Understanding-Windows-NTFS-Permissions.html) is a pretty good primer on NTFS permissions, they have been the same for a while, so the concept should carry over, even though that article wasn't written for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because UAC explicitly adds your user to the ACL of the folder, so you should judt be able to reset the permissions on the folder

Answer (score 0):

Change the owner of the file to someone else, then change the permissions to not include you (Important: Don't set them to "Deny" you, just not include.) There are already plenty of tutorials on how to do that.